# Splitting batch for secondary fermentation over Vanilla

Tags: secondary, stout

I just got a 5 gallon batch of an LME Imperial Stout Recipe to start its magic.  My plan is to split the batch for secondary fermentation.  I plan to move one gallon into a separate jug to finish off over vanilla beans and champagne yeast.

**Any input on how to split the yeast between the two vessels?**

I was thinking about pumping it all into the 5 gallon carboy and pitch the yeast then pumping a gallon ut afte the first day, but I really don't know if that will transfer the proper amount of yeast into the vanilla variety.

**How can I accomplish this best?**

Comment: What's the point of the champagne yeast here?  It will be done fermenting I presume before you want to do this.  So why the new yeast?

Comment: It is part of the recipe.  This is a big stout and they seem to push a very active fermentation.  I am excited about this one.

Answer (score 1):

Let your primary fermentation finish before you do secondary.  At that point you can transfer a gallon and put it on vanilla.  Unless you're planning on aging the beer on vanilla for months (I wouldn't recommend this) you should have no worries about having enough yeast.

I let my carboys sit for a month, undisturbed, before I bottle, and I still have plenty of yeast in suspension for bottle conditioning.